# oracle oraenv script bash

Tags: oracle, scripting

I want to do same commande shell CLi into a script

Command shell without script (CLI)

```
su - oracle
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
export ORACLE_SID=HRPRD
. oraenv
env | grep ora
```

output:

> ```
> USER=oracle
> **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**=/u01/pe/oracle/u/25/bas/lib
> ORACLE_BASE=/u01/pe/oracle
> MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle
> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/u01/pe/oracle/u/25/bas
> PWD=/oracle
> HOME=/oracle
> LOGNAME=oracle
> **ORACLE_HOME**=/u01/pe/oracle/u/25/bas/
> ```

My script

```
rr=`su - oracle`
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
export ORACLE_SID=MySID
uu=`. oraenv`
searchOraHome= `env | grep ora`
echo $searchOraHome
```

output:

> ```
> USER=oracle ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle 
> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/oracle/bin 
> MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle PWD=/oracle HOME=/oracle LOGNAME=oracle
> ```

Why are the variables `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` not present with the script shell?

Is the line:

```
uu=`. oraenv`
```

... not correct?

Comment: i change a ligne of my script with . oraenv instead of uu=`. oraenv` it works  with a script ./test.sh but crontab no i think maybe because of PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin instead of PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/oracle/bin

Answer (score 2):

If you us a shell to execute a command in backticks (`` ` ``), it is executed in a subshell, so all the environment variables it sets are only set in the subshell and are gone when the subshell exits.

You have to "source" the script with

```
. oraenv
```

without the backticks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `oraenv` isn't actually being executed successfully. Are you sure that `oraenv` is in the `$PATH` of the script when it's being called?

You can check where `oraenv` is by running:

`which oraenv`

from your command prompt.

Assuming you're trying to run this from crontab, you can then check the `$PATH` in that environment by adding:

`* * * * *  env > /tmp/environment.txt`

to your crontab, letting it run, removing the crontab entry and then checking the contents of this file.

(or `* * * * * echo $PATH > /emp/path.txt` - but env is fewer characters)

Answer (score 0):

when you run a script from your command prompt it takes the variables from your current session but when you execute it with cron we need to provide the variables

Therefore the difference

Answer (score -2):

I never liked the default oraenv script or the coraenv scripts. so I wrote my own. I use grep and cut to pull out the sid that I am looking for as well as the Oracle home from the /etc/oratab file. I can then set any other environment variables that I want. Things such as email addresses for shell scripts, backup directory, any aliases that I want to use etc. The Oracle provided scripts work ok, I just like being able to control how setting the environment variables works.

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: If the question is, "I want to do same commande shell CLi into a script", then writing a script that replaces the oraenv/coraenv scripts would provide an answer to the question. If you don't like something that Oracle provides, you can always write your own code. Should I have provided a working script for setting environment variables, or should I just provide some parameters for writing a script that can be used by the OP?